# SQL Server Insert Data From Other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database i have tables:

- System Privileges (PrivilegesTable)
- Admins (AdminsTable)
- Admins Privileges (AdminsPrivilegesTable).

I want to insert data in to AdminsPrivilegesTable after insert new admin data i will use trigger for this but i need query to take the admin ID And get all privileges iD From PrivilegesTable and insert it in to AdminsPrivilegesTable. I used this query but does not work.

```
INSERT INTO [AdminsPrivilegesTable]
           ([ID]
           ,[AdminID]
           ,[PrevlgID]
           ,[Status])
     VALUES
           ((SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID)+1,1) FROM AdminsPrivilegesTable)
           ,(SELECT ID FROM Inserted)
           ,(SELECT ID FROM PrivilegesTable)
           ,0)
```

Comment: i would suggest you to avoid trigger: you would handle more control by using the same code of first insert / update operation. About your query: is your `ID IDENTITY`? why are you trying to insert it explicitely by taking the max one? This looks like a bad design. More, if you use the `VALUES` syntax for insert statements, you would specify your records one by one: try with a subquery instead

Comment: Triggers in SQL Server will fire once per batch, so you'll get more than one row in `inserted` -- and you need to design your query that way, if you really want to use triggers.

Comment: The correspondence in the others tables are diferent, may be  get many rows and you hace only one insert statement, from that your query get error. Try create a select query and for the result you most iterate and insert data in your AdminsPrivilegesTable.

Comment: this can be done in a trigger, but your select queries in your values clause is not really clear to me. Can you post some sample data and expected outcome, that would make it much easier to help you

Comment: we actually need more informations about your tables and data: add table sctructure for each of them (e.g.: `SystemPrivileges Table (ID INT IDENTITY, READ INT, CREATE INT, MODIFY INT, EXECUTE INT, DELETE INT, NAME nvarchar(50))` etc,) post also some example data

Comment: Why are you using MAX(ID)+1?  Are you managing your own Identity numbers?  Also, what is your client application that does the INSERT?  Can they call a stored procedure instead?

Comment: Use a MERGE statement with a forced inequalty (`1 = 0`) and use the OUTPUT clause to retrieve all the new IDs in one go as a set, into a temporary table, which you can use to insert into another table.

Comment: your greatest problem with this approach will be the `max(ID) + 1` Never ever do that. Why did you not use an identity column for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample Data** for this demo:

```
CREATE TABLE SYSTEM_PRIVILEGES ([ID] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
                                [NAME] NVARCHAR(50),
                                [ISDEFAULT] INT)
INSERT INTO SYSTEM_PRIVILEGES ([NAME], ISDEFAULT) VALUES
('READ', 1),
('EXECUTE', 0),
('WRITE', 0)

CREATE TABLE ADMINS ([ID] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, [NAME] NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO ADMINS ([NAME]) VALUES
('systemadmin'),
('backupadmin'),
('ITadmin')

CREATE TABLE AdminsPrivilegesTable ([ID] INT IDENTITY,
                                    [AdminID] INT,
                                    [PrevlgID] INT,
                                    [Status] INT)
```

Now, you want to automate the insert in the AdminsPrivilegesTable when a new admin is created. You are standing in front of 2 solutions, imho.

1. Ask the application (or the stored procedure, or whatever it does it) that inserts the Admin row, to make a new insert in another table that might be something like:

**Insert statement**

```
INSERT INTO AdminsPrivilegesTable ([AdminID], [PrevlgID], [Status])
SELECT ADMINS.[ID],
       PREV.[ID],
       1
FROM ADMINS,
SYSTEM_PRIVILEGES PREV
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM AdminsPrivilegesTable T
                  WHERE T.AdminID = ADMINS.ID
                  AND T.PrevlgID = PREV.ID)
```

2. Trigger with same query as above

**Like i said in comments i would suggest 1st one**.

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/320eb/2)

Comment: Thank You Very Much, It's Work

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your query in the trigger for more than one row, because `Inserted` is a table that can hold more than one row.

in your example code it is not clear how to get some values, so I will give an example with pseudo code here

```
INSERT INTO AdminsPrivilegesTable (
  ID, AdminID, PrevlgID, Status)

SELECT ((SELECT ISNULL(MAX(apt.ID)+1,1) FROM AdminsPrivilegesTable apt) -- BAD IDEA
       ,i.ID
       ,(SELECT pt.ID FROM PrivilegesTable pt) -- not clear in your example how to do this
       ,0
FROM   inserted i
```

I need more information about your table schema and some sample data for a better answer